# Is there any difference in verb tense after the phrase "Isn't it about time you"

Tags: verbs, tenses

Isn't it about time you left the hospital?

vs

Isn't it about time you leave the hospital?

or

Isn't it about time you forgave yourself?

vs

Isn't it about time you forgive yourself?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing here with two different constructions which carry quite different nuances of meaning. 'Isn't it about time you left the hospital', is fine. It also carries at least a vague note of censure to the listener.

This first example is nearly always used with the past tense. One exception I can think of is with 'could'. 'You are thirty-five years old. Isn't it time you could drink through a straw?'

I think the second example needs to read. 'Isn't it about time for you to leave the hospital'. I am not sure it is grammatical without them. But that sentence does not contain the same hint of reproof.

Comment: Do you disagree with the example, "isn't it about time you leave the hospital?" This seems particularly common but normally includes a preposition instead of a pronoun: "Isn't it about time *to* leave the hospital?"

Comment: @MrHen I think 'Isn't it about time to leave the hospital' is spoken in a different sense. It merely asks whether or not it is time to leave, and carries no note of reproof. On the other hand 'Isn't it about time you left the hospital' is usually (but not always) censuring of the listener.

Comment: But is it wrong?

Comment: @MrHen We are dealing here with two different constructions which carry quite different nuances of meaning. 'Isn't it about time you left the hospital', is fine. It also carries a note of censure to the listener. But I think the second example needs the words in brackets added. 'Isn't it about time (for you) to leave the hospital'. I am not sure it is grammatical without them. But that sentence does not contain the same hint of reproof.

Comment: Then why does your answer post only mention one of the two constructions? It seems that both are relevant when answering the question.

Comment: @MrHen Because I was clearly having a bad day. I have added my previous comment to the answer.

Comment: Ah, perfectly understandable. :) +1 after the edit.

Answer (score -2):

I think both uses are wrong. More proper would be a preposition followed by the infinitive, e.g. "Isn't it about time for you to forgive yourself?"

Comment: Why? Can you explain?